# Linux RPC call is slow

Tags: c, linux, rpc

The following RPC program executes very slowly on Fedora.
If I change the size of the `name` buffer from 999 characters to 512 in `llist.x`, then it's working fast.
I don't know why.
If anyone knows the reason, please let me know!

Note: Please compile the following programs and execute the server then the client.
(*For me, it takes 3 seconds for 30 loops.*)

**llist.c**

```
#include "llist.h"
#define PRINT_TIME  (!gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) && printf(" %lf",tv.tv_sec+(tv.tv_usec/1000000.0)))

struct timeval tv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
CLIENT *cl;
int *result,i=0;

cl = clnt_create("localhost", PRINTER, PRINTER_V1, "tcp");
if (cl == NULL) {
            clnt_pcreateerror("Cant Create Client Handle");
    printf("error: could not connect to server.\n");
    return 1;
}

    ST1 key[1];
    ST1_stuff  key_x;

    /*key_x.ST1_stuff_val = key;
    key_x.ST1_stuff_len = 1;
*/
    while(i<30)
    {
            printf("\n %d -> start - ",i);
            PRINT_TIME;
            result = sei_conf_test_keys2_1(&key_x,cl);
            if (result == NULL) {
    printf("error: RPC failed!\n");
    return 1;
    }
            printf("\nresult = %d ",*result);
            i++;
            printf("\n end - ");
            PRINT_TIME;
            printf("\n -------------------------------------");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**llist_svc_proc.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "llist.h"

int result;

int *sei_conf_test_keys2_1_svc(ST1 *lst, struct svc_req *req)
{
   result = 0;
   return &result;
}
```

**llist.x**

```
 struct s1{
    char name[999];              /* <===== HERE */
 };
 typedef struct s1 ST1;

 typedef ST1 ST1_stuff[1];


 program PRINTER {
    version PRINTER_V1 {
            int SEI_CONF_TEST_KEYS2(ST1_stuff) = 10;
    } = 1;
 } = 0x2fffffff;
```

**makefile**

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o
CLNT = llist
SRVR = llist_svc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

SRVR_OBJ = llist_svc_proc.o llist_xdr.o llist_svc.o
CLNT_OBJ = llist.o llist_xdr.o llist_clnt.o

.c.o:
        gcc -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

default: $(CLNT) $(SRVR)

$(CLNT): $(CLNT_OBJ) llist.h
        gcc -o $(CLNT) $(CLNT_OBJ)

$(SRVR): $(SRVR_OBJ) llist.h
        gcc -o $(SRVR) $(SRVR_OBJ)
clean:
        rm *.o $(CLNT) $(SRVR)
        rm -f llist_xdr.c llist.h llist_clnt.c llist_svc.c
        rm core
```

Comment: You should include the `rpcgen` command in your makefile

Comment: I see the same time kind of time difference on a RHEL6.7 system `1.19 secs` vs `0.03 secs`

Comment: Also `rm -f core` will stop complaints about it not being there.

Comment: I would guess that sendsz and recvsz automatically do something bad at 999 that they don't do at 512.

Comment: the posted question contains `llist.c`, `llist_serv_proc.c`, `llist.x`, and `makefile`.  What is the `llist.x`?   Where is the `llist.h`?

Comment: in file: `llist.c`  the parameter to main: `argc` and `argv[]` are not used.  missing `#include <rpc/rpc.h>`,

Answer (score 1):

The time increase seems to be connected with the maximum allowed
data in one TCP package.

Using a network analyser, one sees, that with size 999 there are **167 packages**
whereas with size 512 only about **79 packets** are sent between client and server.
The maximum data size per package seems to be 4000 bytes.

If you need performance, think about switching to UDP which seems not be limited by the maximum package size and additional overhead.

Comment: One does not simply switch from TCP to UDP without ignoring the consequences.

Comment: @fsaintjacques yes, of course, but at least for traffic on localhost, like in the question of the OP, UDP should be fine.